# Get JSON values in another function

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I have a problem with a JSON. It looks like this - just an excerpt:

```
{
    "Pizza Margharita": {
        "id": "0",        
        "price1": "4,50"        
    },
    "Pizza Caprese ": {
        "id": "1",
        "price1": "4,00"
    },
    "Pizza Salami": {
        "id": "2",
        "price1": "4,00"
    }
}
```

My function looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('data/food01.json', function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(name, price) {
            $('section#food01').find('ul').append('<li><a id="+order' + price.id + '" href="#order"><h3>' + name + '</h3><span>' + price.price1 + '</span></a></li>');
        }); <!-- /each -->



        $('#food01 li a').live('click', data, function(name, price) {
            var foo = name;
            $('#foodname h3').append(foo);
        });
    });
});
```

With the `$.each()` I get the data from the JSON and append it to `<li>`-elements. That's working fine. Now I want to get the values in another function that is still included in the $getJSON function. Is that possible or what am I doing wrong? If anybody could help me would be awesome - thanks a lot!

Comment: `live` is deprecated. Use `on` instead.

Comment: If you could explain the problem a little more with your `html` (preferably also in a jsbin or jsfiddle), along with what it is you want to do, it will make it easier to get a solution

Answer (score 0):

Data is accessible in your function, so you don't need to pass it in!

```
$(function() {
        $.getJSON('data/food01.json', function(data) {

            $.each(data, function(name, price) {
                $('section#food01').find('ul').append('<li><a id="+order' + price.id + '" href="#order"><h3>' + name + '</h3><span>' + price.price1 + '</span></a></li>');
            }); <!-- /each -->



            $('#food01 li a').live('click', function(name, price) {
                //you can just access data here...
    var foo = name;
                $('#foodname h3').append(foo);
            });
        });

});
```

Comment: Something smells odd about this.

Comment: That seems like it would be more appropriate as a comment, no?

Comment: why? I changed the code to reflect the change and 'data' is a perfectly valid variable within the live function as its contained within the getJSON function??

Comment: Thx for your answer but that's not working. Tried that before. Any other suggestions. Problem is that I can't access the data of the JSON in the second function?!? "var foo = name" responses [Object][object] if I put it in an alert.

Comment: Well that was what I wanted to say. By the time the `.live()` is ready to fire, your `$.each()` has finished looping through the data `object`. If you want to do anything with the name and price variables, you should do that in the $.each()

Comment: Is it possible to append the variable just to one $('#food01 li a'), not for each - that's my problem. I don't need it for each, but just for one specific element.

Comment: How would you identify that one element? By name or by index or some other rule? Those are the details we are asking for

Comment: First I click one of the links that I created with the first request -> .append('<li><a href="...">...</li>'). To find out which element is clicked I use .index. The next step should be to put the JSON values of that specific element in either variables or directly .append them to the element ($('#foodname h3'). You know what I mean? Btw - thx a lot!!!

Comment: See my answer, if it doesn't help, create a jsbin if possible and explain a 'lil more

Answer (score 0):

The data argument that is passed to `live` or `on` can be accessed through the event's data property. Here is an example of how you could iterate through `data`, for instance:

```
    $('#food01 li a').on('click', null, data, function(e) {
        $.each(e.data, function(name, price){
            var foo = name;
            $('#foodname h3').append(foo);
        });
    });
```

I am not sure what you need to do with `data`, but this can easily be adapted.

Comment: This one seems more on target.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at an answer:

```
$(function() {

    $.getJSON('data/food01.json', function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(name, price) {

            $('section#food01').find('ul').append('<li><a id="+order' + price.id + '" href="#order"><h3>' + name + '</h3><span>' + price.price1 + '</span></a></li>');

            if( /* some condition like price > 100 or name == 'Margharita'*/ ){
                $('#food01 li a').on('click', function() {
                    $('#foodname h3').append(name);
                }); // click 

            }  // if

        }); // each

    }); // getJSON

}); // ready
```

Comment: Took a look at your answer and tried some things. It would be possible to compare the .index of the clicked link and the value id e.g. "id":"0" of the JSON element. Something like this if(indexNo == price.id ) {} Problem is that I don't have the .index of the clicked link before I click it. Other conditions probably won't make sense. Any idea? ;) I'll post an example - wait a sec pls...

Answer (score 0):

It works!

```
$(function() {
     $.getJSON('data/food01.json', function(data) {

         $.each(data, function(name, price) {
              $('section#food01').find('ul').append('<li><a id="order'+price.id+'" href="#order"><h3>'+name+'</h3><span>'+price.price1+'</span></a></li>');
              var foodname = name;
              var id = price.id;
              $('#food01 li a').live('click', function(name, price){
                  var indexNo = $(this);
                  var indexNo2 = ($('#food01 a').index(indexNo));

                  if(indexNo2 == id) {
                         $('#foodname h3').append(foodname);
                  }<!-- if -->
              });<!-- /live -->
          });<!-- /each -->

     });<!-- /getJSON -->
   });<!-- /function -->
```